# mapping values between data frames R

Tags: r, dataframe

let's create example data:

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"), X1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"),
                 X2=c("B", "A", "D", "F", "C"))
df2 <- data.frame(date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"), 
                  A=c("3", "4", "2", "1", "5"),
                  B=c("6", "2", "5", "1", "1"),
                  C=c("1", "4", "5", "2", "3"),
                  D=c("67", "67", "63", "61", "62"),
                  F=c("31", "33", "35", "31", "38"))
```

So I have two data frames and I want to match values from df2 to df by date and X1 and X2 and create new variables for those. What makes this tricky for me is that matched values in df2 are in colnames. End result should look like this:

```
> result
        date X1 X2 Var1 Var2
1 2017-01-01  A  B    3    6
2 2017-01-02  B  A    2    4
3 2017-01-03  C  D    5   63
4 2017-01-04  D  F   61   31
5 2017-01-05  F  C   38    3

result <- data.frame(date=c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05"), 
                     X1=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "F"),
                     X2=c("B", "A", "D", "F", "C"),
                     Var1=c("3", "2", "5", "61", "38"),
                     Var2=c("6", "4", "63", "31", "3"))
```

I wanted to use mapvalues, but couldn't figure it out. Second thought was to go long format (melt) with df2 and try then, but failed there as well.

Ok, here is my best try, just feels that there could be more efficient way,  if you have to create multiple (>50) new variables to data frame.

```
df2.long <- melt(df2, id.vars = c("date"))

df$Var1 <- na.omit(merge(df, df2.long, by.x = c("date", "X1"), by.y = c("date", "variable"), all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE))[,4]
df$Var2 <- na.omit(merge(df, df2.long, by.x = c("date", "X2"), by.y = c("date", "variable"), all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE))[,5]
```

Comment: All good answers, thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possibility with `mapply`:

```
df$Var1 <- mapply(function(day, col) df2[df2$date==day, as.character(col)], 
                  day=df$date, col=df$X1)
df$Var2 <- mapply(function(day, col) df2[df2$date==day, as.character(col)], 
                  day=df$date, col=df$X2)

df
#        date X1 X2 Var1 Var2
#1 2017-01-01  A  B    3    6
#2 2017-01-02  B  A    2    4
#3 2017-01-03  C  D    5   63
#4 2017-01-04  D  F   61   31
#5 2017-01-05  F  C   38    3
```

**NB:**
If you have more columns to modify (not just 2 like in your example), you can use `lapply` to loop over the columns `X.`:

```
df[, paste0("Var", 1:2)] <- lapply(df[,paste0("X", 1:2)], 
                                   function(value) {
                                      mapply(function(day, col) df2[df2$date==day, as.character(col)], 
                                             day=df$date, col=value)})
```

Comment: yeah, thanks. Got headache already, as my original data was `"data.table" "data.frame"`, so function was returning only X1 to new variable, but transforming it to only data frame corrected that. I don't have ability to understand why.

Comment: @Viitama if you're actually working with `data.table`s, David's answer could be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm noob, I don't when it changes from one to another. If there is no match, what should I do to get NA instead of `numeric(0)`. I can always correct them later, or build a function from that, but is there something I can do inside mapply?

Comment: you can check if the value is among the colnames and if not return NA

Comment: Yeah, `as.numeric` in front of your code will solve this. Now it returns list inside data.frame column?? but thanks, I got it working!

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
df2_m <- group_by(df2, date) %>% 
    gather('X1', 'var', -date)

left_join(df, df2_m) %>% 
    left_join(df2_m, by = c('date', 'X2' = 'X1')) %>%
    rename(Var1 = var.x, Var2 = var.y) -> result
```

Answer (score 3):

An double melt > join > dcast option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table) # v>=1.10.0
dcast(
  melt(setDT(df), 1L)[ # melt the first table by date
    melt(setDT(df2), 1L),  # melt the second table by date
    on = .(date, value = variable), # join by date and the letters
    nomatch = 0L], # remove everything that wasn't matched
  date ~ variable, # convert back to long format
  value.var = c("value", "i.value")) # take both values columns

#          date value_X1 value_X2 i.value_X1 i.value_X2
# 1: 2017-01-01        A        B          3          6
# 2: 2017-01-02        B        A          2          4
# 3: 2017-01-03        C        D          5         63
# 4: 2017-01-04        D        F         61         31
# 5: 2017-01-05        F        C         38          3
```

Comment: nice, just beat me to it

Answer (score 2):

We can use `match` to get the column index of 'df2' from the 'X1' and 'X2' columns, `cbind` with the sequence of rows, use the row/column index to extract the values in 'df2', and assign the output to create the 'Var' columns

```
df[paste0("Var", 1:2)] <-  lapply(df[2:3], function(x)
          df2[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df2), match(x, names(df2)[-1]))])
df
#        date X1 X2 Var1 Var2
#1 2017-01-01  A  B    3    6
#2 2017-01-02  B  A    2    4
#3 2017-01-03  C  D    5   63
#4 2017-01-04  D  F   61   31
#5 2017-01-05  F  C   38    3
```

Comment: To account for not sequentially matching dates, I guess, it could be `i = match(df$date, df2$date); ...cbind(i, match(..))..` (instead of `1:nrow`)

Answer (score 1):

Using melt and match:

```
df2l<-melt(df2, measure=c("A","B","C","D","F"))
Indices <- match(paste(df$date, df$X1), paste(df2l$date,df2l$variable))
df$Var1 <- df2l$value[Indices]
Indices2 <- match(paste(df$date, df$X2), paste(df2l$date,df2l$variable))
df$Var2 <- df2l$value[Indices2]
```